# SQL Server scheduling by script

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-job

I created a job to execute a procedure every 5 minutes but the job has no history of being run and also when I execute `exec sp_help_jobactivity @job_name = 'Update Subscription flags'`, I get empty result. I also checked `sysjobschecdules` that has 0 for next_run_date and time. My procedure is compiled and works fine when i execute it manually. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong here. Here's the schedule:

```
--Add a Job to SQL Server Agent
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
     @job_name = N'Update Subscription flags'; -- the job name
GO



GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
     @job_name         = N'Update Subscription flags' -- Job name specified in sp_add_job
    ,@step_name        = N'Step - Set subscription flags to false' -- step name
    ,@database_name    = 'db' --Database Name
    ,@command          = N'EXEC UpdateSubscriptionFlags;' -- SQL Command
GO


--Attach server name. Not needed if you are creating job on same server.
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver
     @job_name     = N'Update Subscription flags'
    ,@server_name = N'DESKTOP-3DR2LAE\SQLEXPRESS'; -- LOCAL by default
GO


GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_schedule
     @schedule_name          = N'Daily - Every 5 Minutes' -- specify the schedule name
    ,@freq_type              = 4 -- 4 indicates job is scheduled daily, refer msdn link for reference
    ,@freq_interval          = 1 -- The days that a job is executed and depends on the value of
    ,@freq_subday_type       = 4 --At specified time (At specific time/second/minutes/hours)
    ,@freq_subday_interval   = 5 --Run every 5 min once the job is scheduled

GO


--Attach Created Job name to Schedule name
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_attach_schedule
     @job_name         = N'Update Subscription flags' -- Job Name
    ,@schedule_name    = N'Daily - Every 5 Minutes' ; -- Schedule Name
GO
```

Comment: Can you run the job manually using exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=? Also curious as how in your SERVER_name you have SQLEXPRESS, considering SQL Express edition doens't have a SQL Server Agent

Comment: Nice spot on `N'DESKTOP-3DR2LAE\SQLEXPRESS'` @DKramer; could well be that the OP is mistaken about the version he's using.

Comment: I executed exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=? and got another error which turns out, is because my SQL server agent is not running and throws error when I start it. The error I got is : **the request failed or the service didn't respond in a timely fashion**